# Qt connect - object emits signal before connect is issued

Tags: qt, qt-signals

I have following `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QtQml>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "database/uepeoplemodel.h"
#include "core/uestatus.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    UeStatus* ueApplicationStatus=new UeStatus(qApp);
    UePeopleModel* uePeopleModel=new UePeopleModel(qApp);

    QObject::connect(uePeopleModel,
                     SIGNAL(ueSignalDatabaseConnectionChanged(UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus)),
                     ueApplicationStatus,
                     SLOT(ueSignalDatabaseConnectionChanged(UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus)));

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("uePeopleModel",
                                             uePeopleModel);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ueApplicationStatus",
                                             ueApplicationStatus);
    engine.addImageProvider(QLatin1String("uePeopleModel"),
                            uePeopleModel);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Now, inside `main.cpp` I create two objects from classes:

```
UeStatus* ueApplicationStatus=new UeStatus(qApp);
UePeopleModel* uePeopleModel=new UePeopleModel(qApp);
```

and I connect signal from `UePeopleModel` to slot in `ueApplicationStatus`:

```
QObject::connect(uePeopleModel,
    SIGNAL(ueSignalDatabaseConnectionChanged(UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus)), 
    ueApplicationStatus,
    SLOT(ueSignalDatabaseConnectionChanged(UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus)));
```

The problem is when `uePeopleModel` is created, the signal is emmited inside constructor:

```
UePeopleModel::UePeopleModel(QObject* parent)
    : QSqlQueryModel(parent),
      QQuickImageProvider(QQmlImageProviderBase::Image,
                          QQmlImageProviderBase::ForceAsynchronousImageLoading)
{
    if(!QSqlDatabase::connectionNames().contains(UePosDatabase::UeDatabaseConnectionNames::DATABASE_CONNECTION_NAME_PEOPLE,
                                                 Qt::CaseInsensitive))
    {
        this->ueSetDatabase(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(UePosDatabase::DATABASE_DRIVER,
                                                      UePosDatabase::UeDatabaseConnectionNames::DATABASE_CONNECTION_NAME_PEOPLE));
    }   // if

    this->ueDatabase().setHostName(/*this->uePosSettings()->ueDbHostname()*/UePosDatabase::UeDatabaseConnectionParameters::DATABASE_HOSTNAME);
    this->ueDatabase().setDatabaseName(/*this->uePosSettings()->ueDbName()*/UePosDatabase::UeDatabaseConnectionParameters::DATABASE_NAME);
    this->ueDatabase().setUserName(/*this->uePosSettings()->ueDbUser()*/UePosDatabase::UeDatabaseConnectionParameters::DATABASE_USERNAME);
    this->ueDatabase().setPassword(/*this->uePosSettings()->ueDbPassword()*/UePosDatabase::UeDatabaseConnectionParameters::DATABASE_PASSWORD);

    if(this->ueDatabase().open())
    {
        emit this->ueSignalDatabaseConnectionChanged(CONNECTED);
        this->setQuery(UePosDatabase::UeSqlQueries::UeTablePeople::SQL_QUERY_GET_ALL_PEOPLE,
                       this->ueDatabase());
/*
        if(this->lastError().isValid())
            qDebug() << this->lastError();
*/
    }
    else
    {
        emit this->ueSignalDatabaseConnectionChanged(NOT_CONNECTED);
//        qDebug() << this->ueDatabase().lastError();
    }

//    qDebug() << this->ueDatabase().connectionNames();
}   // default constructor
```

before `connect` is issued and therfore `ueApplicationStatus` object does not catch is with slot. Does anyone has idea how to get rid of this situation?

Comment: "The problem is when uePeopleModel is created, the signal is emmited inside constructor:" Well, don't do that! Seriously, what kind of a question is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the constructor to open the connection with the database.

Use the constructor only to instantiate other classes, initialize variables, allocate memory and so on.

In your case, your constructor should be used to initialize the database, but you could create another method with:

```
if(this->ueDatabase().open())
    {
        emit this->ueSignalDatabaseConnectionChanged(CONNECTED);
        this->setQuery(UePosDatabase::UeSqlQueries::UeTablePeople::SQL_QUERY_GET_ALL_PEOPLE,
                       this->ueDatabase());
    }
    else
    {
        emit this->ueSignalDatabaseConnectionChanged(NOT_CONNECTED);
}
```

This method would be called after the `connect` you have in your `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem by adding method `void ueConnectToDatabase()` and moved the content of constructor into it and redefined `main.cpp` as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    UeStatus* ueApplicationStatus=new UeStatus(qApp);
    UePeopleModel* uePeopleModel=new UePeopleModel(qApp);

    QObject::connect(uePeopleModel,
                     SIGNAL(ueSignalDatabaseConnectionChanged(UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus)),
                     ueApplicationStatus,
                     SLOT(ueSignalDatabaseConnectionChanged(UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus)));

    uePeopleModel->ueConnectToDatabase();

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("uePeopleModel",
                                             uePeopleModel);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ueApplicationStatus",
                                             ueApplicationStatus);
    engine.addImageProvider(QLatin1String("uePeopleModel"),
                            uePeopleModel);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Now the object is created, signal and slot connected and AFTER this the connection to database occurs.

Comment: Hehehe, the same solution I proposed :) Amazing ;)

Comment: @Tarod thanks anyway! Today I am not thinking at the 100% of capacities. I should had remembered solution without posting question :).